# why map not returning correct result

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to loop through an array of dom elements and only return the dom element if it matches a specific criteria. In the case below if the id attribute is equal to the value of "0" and it has a child element with the class name record. 
I have tried the below code but it returns element 0 always even if it does not have a child with the class record.

```
var el = shows.map(function(index, element) {
    if (this.id == "0" && $(element).children('.record')) return this;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$(element).children('.record')` to `$(element).children('.record').length`.

If jQuery doesn't find any elements, it returns an empty array, which JavaScript converts to `true`.

Comment: Thanks Rocket. Is there a method that stops the loop if it reaches a true value. map, filter and each go through all the elements even if it finds one that matches the criteria I had.

Comment: @Chapsterj: You can use `.each`.  It doesn't return a value, so you'll have to set variable to the found value.  If you `return false;` from the callback to `.each`, it'll break the loop.

Comment: Thanks so there is no method in jquery that will return an element and stop the loop when it finds that element to return you are saying?

Comment: @Chapsterj: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

try specifcally returning null in cases where you don't want the item in the mapped array.

```
var el = shows.map(function(index, element) {
    if (this.id == "0" && $(element).children('.record')) 
        return this;
    else
       return null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to using jQuery

```
$(element).filter(function(key, value){
   return $(value).children('.record').length>0;
});
```